# Testing LTO drive with mt and dd

Tags: dd, scsi, tape, read-write

Here are my commands

```
mt -f /dev/st0 rewind
dd if=/dev/st0 of=-
```

As I understand it the first command rewinds my tape in `/dev/st0`, and the second command writes contents of `/dev/st0` to `-`. My questions are

- Where is `-`?
- What is this command doing when it writes the data from the tape to `-`?

The result of the command is:

```
dd: writing to '-': No space left on device
1234567+0 records in
1234566+0 records out
140000000000 bytes (141 GB) copied, 14500.9 s, 9.8 MB/s
```

It appears to me I have written the data to something, but I would like to verify where that data was written.

Is it just reading the tape?

Thanks for the help

Comment: see if there's literally a file `-` you wrote stuff to ... where did you get those commands from?

Comment: find / -name "-" returns nothing, got these commands from another associate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've used tape. However, here's what I believe is happening

```
mt -f /dev/st0 rewind
```

This rewinds the tape in `/dev/st0` ready for writing. Once the device is closed the tape is then automatically rewound because you didn't use the non-rewind device probably called something like `/dev/nst0`. Obviously in this instance the second part of this operation is effectively a no-op.

```
dd if=/dev/st0 of=-
```

This reads as many blocks of 512 bytes from the tape device `/dev/st0` as possible, and writes them to a file called `-` in your current directory. (Specifically, `-` is not an alternative name for *stdout*.) For a tape this can cause a lot of overruns and rewinds as it tries to handle partial reads from the typically larger block size (often 4K or 8K, but can be much larger). At the end of the `dd` operation the device is closed and the tape will be rewound automatically.

Depending on the block size you may want something like this (I've called the output file `tape.dat` rather than `-`)

```
dd bs=4K if=/dev/st0 > tape.dat
```

Comment: roaima, thanks for the reply. This was meant to be a test of the functionality of the tape drive and the server to make sure they were installed correctly. I believe we can call the install good based on the output. I see no file called `-` on the server. Is it possible it wrote to `-` but since `-` doesn't exist nothing was written, or would it create `-` and then write to it? As noted before, find / -name "-" returns nothing.

Comment: You got an error, `dd: writing to '-': No space left on device` so the file was created and it filled the disk. Is it possible someone else removed it?

Comment: It is possible but highly unlikely someone removed it. I guess my mission now is to locate `-` to delete it.

Comment: `less ./-` returns no such file or directory. As noted before, `find / -name "-"` returns nothing. `find -name '-' -exec less {} +` returns nothing. Is there anything else to try?

Comment: Have any of your disks run out of space (`df -h`)? If not, the file has been deleted

Comment: No disks are full.

Comment: Could be tmpfs if you have 141GB of RAM/Swap ;-) could also be autocleaned if it was in a tmp dir that is cleaned by your system regularly